# Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 405 Laravel Vue api

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, pusher

I am building a spa with laravel 5.4 as back-end and vue js as front-end. I have set up laravel broadcasting event, and it's working fine with localhost:8000/event. "Event" being route where I have set up broadcasting....

Now the problem is when I connect it with my vuejs front-end

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');


window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '********************',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/login',
    encrypted: false
});
```

and

```
created(){
        window.Echo.private('testChannel1')
        .listen('TaskEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
```

all these are in the main.js file itself, I am getting this error

```
pusher.js?b3eb:593 POST http://localhost:8000/api/user/login 405 (Method Not Allowed)

pusher.js?b3eb:626 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 405
```

Here I am using jwt auth for authentication system. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your `routes/channels.php` you will need to add

```
Broadcast::channel('testChannel1', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

You are listening on a private channel, for this to work you will need to define the authorisation of that private channel.

Ofcourse you can change the return statement to whatever suites your needs.

If you do not wish for this channel to be private you could change:

```
window.Echo.private('testChannel1')
```

to

```
window.Echo.channel('testChannel1')
```

Comment: hi @milo526,  where did u get that $user variable from in anonymous function?  I did set up broadcast channel in channels.php but i dint do $user variable?? i am using jwt

Comment: How do i set authorization?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#authorizing-channels)